# How can I use <ui:style> with a FlexTable?

Tags: gwt

I'm learning to use GWT 2.0 and I'm trying to convert the StockWatcher demo to use the UiBinder. the demo uses stocksFlexTable.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(0, "watchListHeader"); to add styles, but when I add <ui:style> to my XML and move my CSS I can't seem to figure out how to make the style work because there is no  stocksFlexTable.getRowFormatter().addStyle(). Does <ui:style> just not work with FlexTables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to deal with it as well with no success. I believe though that dynamic widgets such as FlexTable are not fully supported for obvious reasons - i.e. you can't preset the style for the nth row when you don't really know how many rows the table will hold. Also, providing some arbitrary way to do it for the first only, or odd rows etc. would require more expressive power than what the GWT developers seem keen to offer (they try to stick close to XHTML) and i believe they state at the wiki at somepoint that declarative syntax is by no means a templating language. Anyway, you can always experiment with @UiFactory and @UiField(provided=true) to try and stick close to GWT recommendations. But still, you ll have to set any such values programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had success by removing the  section completely and moving all of the css for the FlexTable into the application css file.